# Insert list into multiple tables with foreign key relationship Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, optimization, entity-framework-6

I have `Document` table with `DocumentID` (PK) & `DocumentName` columns. 
Another table `Connector_Document` with `ConnectorID` (PK), `DocumentID` (FK) & some other columns.

I have a `List<Document>` & `ConnectorId` as input. I want to save `List<Document>` in `Document` table, get `DocumentID` of all these & save in `Connector_Document` table with the provided `connectorID` & fetched `DocumentId`.

With following input

```
List<Document> documents = new List<Document>{new Document{ DocumentName ="test1"},
new Document{DocumentName ="test2"}};
int connectorId = 5
```

My output should be:

Document Table

```
DocumentID      DocumentName
-----------------------------
    10              test1
    11              test2
```

`Connector_Document` table:

```
ConnectorID    DocumentID
      5             10
      5             11
```

I know I can loop through the List, add in document table get it's PK & use the same to insert in Connector_Document table. But, I don't think this is the efficient way & I am expecting some way  should be provided by EF for this. Someone help me in this.

Had it been a single object instead of list, I could have done this:

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
{
    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        context.Documents.Add(document);
        context.SaveChanges();

        if (connectorDocument != null)
        {
            connectorDocument.DocumentID = document.DocumentID;
            context.Connector_Document.Add(connectorDocument);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        dbContextTransaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

I am using Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AddRange` to save the Documents list the way you want. But because you need a separate object for each Connector_Document row, you will still need a way to create them. I would suggest something like this:

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
{
    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        context.Documents.AddRange(documents);
        context.SaveChanges();

        var connectorDocuments = from doc in documents
                                 select new Connector_Document 
                                 {
                                     ConnectorId = connectorId,
                                     DocumentId = doc.DocumentId
                                 };
        context.Connector_Document.AddRange(connectorDocuments);
        context.SaveChanges();
        dbContextTransaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a transaction here. Hence you have defined the relationships correctly, below code should work without any issue.You don't need to manipulate data insertion manually for the related objects.Those are done by the EF.

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
      {

          foreach (var d in documents)
            {
               context.Documents.Add(d);
               context.SaveChanges();
            }
      }
```